# Angular *ngFor TrackBy Element over 2 levels of loops

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have 2  *ngFor loops in my code somewhat like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let page of pages; trackBy: trackByPageId" class="page">
    <app-item-component *ngFor="let item of page; trackBy: trackByItemID"
                        [item]="item">
    </app-item-component>
</div>
```

Now the items may be moved from one page to another and i do not want the app-item Component to re-initialize when i move it between pages.

Using angular's trackBy allows array items to be moved without the components running ngOnDestroy ang ngOnInit again, but as soon as im using 2 nested loops and an item moves from one list to another, this doesn't work anymore.

For Example, moving an item in the array like this:
`pages[0]items[0] -> pages[1]items[0]`
would cause the item component to re-initialize.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have 1 Input property inside your .ts

```
@Input() checker: boolean;
```

and use it inside .html

```
<div *ngFor="let page of pages; trackBy: trackByPageId" class="page">
   <ng-container ngIf="checker"> 
    <app-item-component *ngFor="let item of page; trackBy: trackByItemID"
                        [item]="item">
    </app-item-component>
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

This way it will render depending on the containers ngIf

Comment: Im sorry, i don't see how this could solve my problem. I added more description to the question to clarify my problem.